# Export WiFi Certificates

Tags: wireless, certificates

I use Ubuntu in my Laptop. I also have a Nokia N8 phone. To connect N8 to "WPA2 Enterprise WiFi", I need to export some certificate from my laptop.

The page http://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=B-2D1QR8C2c explains how to export the necessary certificate from Windows 7. Can you please explain how to export the certificate from Ubuntu?

Simply copying the file in /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you installed a digital certificate on Ubuntu to access the wireless?  Most people use a password rather than a certificate.  If you did install a certificate, then you should be able to go back to where you installed it ( right click networking -> edit connection -> 802.1x security and see what file it points to for the CA certificate.

Comment: The certificate you want should be in `/etc/ssl/certs`.  Try the command `find /etc/ssl/certs -type d` to see if you have any certificates there.

Answer (score 1):

As Psusi pointed out, you can find the particular certificate that your laptop connection uses through the NetworkManager interface. Since using the certificate directly didn't work for you, I suspect that you may need to convert the certificate to a format that your phone accepts.

To convert from a PEM file to a DER file, you can use OpenSSL:

`openssl x509 -inform PEM -outform DER -in Input.pem -out Output.der`

If you don't have OpenSSL installed, you can find it in package manager.

Comment: You may need to use `.cer` as the output file extension.